# Need to change smarty file into zend file

Tags: zend-framework, smarty

HI here i have smarty file and i need to convert into zend..
How can i change smarty to zend? its tpl file

```
<div id="add-user-form" class="form">
    <form action="/account/login" method="post">
    {{input_text type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value=$smarty.server.REDIRECT_URL|default:"/"}}

    <div class="contain">
        <div class="fieldgrp">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="field"><p><h3>Enter&nbsp;User&nbsp;Credentials</h3></p></div>
        </div>
    <div class="fieldgrp">
        <label for="login_name">Username </label>
        <div class="field">{{input_text name="login" id="login_name" class="longfield" maxlength="100"}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldgrp">
        <label for="login_password">Password </label>
        <div class="field">{{input_text type="password" name="password" id="login_password" class="longfield" maxlength="100"}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldgrp">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="field"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: I missed this one. Seems that there is a [dupe question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104569/need-to-convert-smarty-file-to-zend/5110357#5110357) which I did answer, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the Smarty code with the HTML it generates....

eg.

```
{{input_text name="login" id="login_name" class="longfield" maxlength="100"}}
```

becomes

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="login_name" class="longfield" maxlength="100">
```

But past that, this question doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: my actual intention is, i m using smarty plugins and would like to trace and convert or use zend functions